# How to set default folder permission for specific drive in win10?

Tags: windows-10, permissions

I have a hard-drive D: that always create no permissions when I create a new folder on this drive. Is there a way to change the default permissions?

[image]

I set up security on D: that all child object permissions are inherited but it does not help at all.

[image]
That checkbox unchecks itself after it runs through all existing folders.

This drive was old OS drive before I upgraded to a SSD.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have a feeling that the issue could be related to the principal "Everyone" instead of "administrators", will change that when I have time and make note.

Comment: After initial testing it seems that the issue might be related to the Principal not equal to the Owner.